# Drawing graph in Racket

Tags: racket

I was developing a math research programm in Racket using Graph Theory an I need to draw the datas. Is there a library to do it?

Example of graph:

```
‘((1 2) (1 7) (2 3) (3 2) (4 2) (7 4))
```

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfzH5.png)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `graph` is allows you to draw graphs with the help of GraphViz.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/graph/index.html#%28part._.Graphviz%29